# How should I handle date and time inside a group live chat?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time

Currently I am programming a group live chat for a small project in PHP. During programming I came across a big question: How should I handle date and time?

The chat is designed in such a way that theoretically an infinite number of people can write with each other in a chat room.

Now, when someone writes a new message, I naturally want to display the current user date and time in the message so that the user knows afterwards when he wrote which message. I solved this by calling a function in JavaScript when adding a message, which adds the message in the chat and then stores it in the database via AJAX.

To set the time in the new message, I proceeded as follows:

```
let messageWrapper = $( "#message-wrapper" ),
    newMessage     = $( "#template" ).clone(),
    newMessageDate = new Date();

newMessage.find( ".time" ).text( newMessageDate.getHours() + ":" + +( newMessageDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + newMessageDate.getMinutes() );

messageWrapper.append( newMessage );
```

After adding the message I now write it into my database. For this I use AJAX:

```
let data = {
    action: "create_message",
    created: newMessageDate.getTime()
};

$.post( ajax_url, data, function () {
} ).success( function () {
    console.log( "Message successfully saved in DB" );
} );
```

As you can see, I use the function `getTime()` here, which gives me the timestamp of the date.

In PHP I now receive the timestamp and change it to my database timestamp format so I can store it in the database correctly:

```
$created           = $_POST['created'];
$formatted_created = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $created / 1000 );
```

But here I noticed that the timestamp is in UTC format and does not match the time in the new message. I thought that this won't be a problem and I just have to respect the timezone when displaying it, but that's not that easy.

Assuming person A comes from America and writes in the chat, then his time is shown and I get the timestamp in UTC format. On the other side of the world person B is sitting and has a different time zone. There the browser uses the local time and the timestamp is UTC time.

However, I now have the problem that I do not know how to display the message to the user in the correct format, depending on the users time zone.

Of course PHP offers the possibility to set a timezone, but then that would only be a certain timezone, which is useless in my case:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $message->created ) );
```

My question is, how should I proceed in this case? How should I handle my date and time for a new message?

PS: I know this is a lot of theory and not every developer likes it. However, I've tried hard to describe the problem as best as I can. If something is missing for clarification, I am more than willing to add it.

Comment: The way I've dealt with this is to avoid formatting dates in the PHP code, leaving everything as unix timestamps and doing the formatting in the client-side code so it can use the user's timezone. I also don't trust the time from the client and instead use the current timestamp when the record is inserted.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sounds interesting. How are you doing is (technically)? Are you handling it inside a `<script>` tag? And how do you get the timestamp during the .append() to the chat? Because I like this idea.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I would love to hear how you've done this. Have you printed an array of messages inside a `<script></script>` and worked with this inside a JS document.ready function or how?

Comment: It's a difficult to describe briefly in comments. I'll try to make an answer with a minimal example and a better description.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks a lot! This would really help me getting the messages into the chat with the correct date and time.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Hi Mate, do you got any update for me? I'm still struggling with this task.